# 3 elements of array is empty.why?

Tags: python

I cannot catch 3 elements of array.
My code is like

```
lines = [['bcac', '3'], ['abcd', '14'], ['abccjg', '92'], ['bcaddgie', '2'], ['abcd', '6'], ['cb', '200']]
query = [['b'], ['a'], ['abcd'], ['gagioheo'], ['cb']]

line_alpha = [[int(line[1]) for line in lines if a[0]==line[0][0]] for a in query]
print(line_alpha)
```

and console print out `[[3, 2], [14, 92, 6], [], [], []]`.
But I wanna get `[[3, 2], [14, 92, 6], [14,6], [], [200]]`.
I cannot understand why 3 elements is empty.In my code,I wrote `for a in "query"`,I designate "query" so I think for statement rotates 5 times(it means number of elements of query)How can I fix this?

Comment: What is the output you are trying to get? Can you show the expected output?

Comment: They show the expected output

Comment: Check your desired output first. 
It should be [[3, 2], [14, 92, 6], [14, 2, 6], [], [200]]

Answer (score 0):

The output is right according to your code. In order to get what you want, you can either

1. change your `query` to `['b', 'a', 'abcd', 'gagioheo', 'cb']`
2. or change `a[0]==line[0][0]` to `a[0][0]==line[0][0]`.

`a` is a list containing `str`.

I am not sure what is your need. `query` currently is a list of list of string. I thought maybe just a list of string suites the situation.

Answer (score 0):

'query' is 2 dimension array. Use `query[0][0]` to get first character instead of `query[0]`.

```
line_alpha = [[int(line[1]) for line in lines if a[0][0]==line[0][0]] for a in query]
```

Edit: Maybe I misunderstood.

```
line_alpha = [[int(line[1]) for line in lines if line[0].startswith(a[0])] for a in query]
```

this match your required answer.

Answer (score 0):

Other people talk you ,what happened about use your code.
I talk you how to achieve your purpose.
Maybe you could try re.
Use re can do what you want.

```
import re
lines = [['bcac', '3'], ['abcd', '14'], ['abccjg', '92'], ['bcaddgie', '2'], ['abcd', '6'], ['cb', '200']]
query = [['b'], ['a'], ['abcd'], ['gagioheo'], ['cb']]

line_alpha = [[int(line[1]) for line in lines if re.compile('^'+a[0]).search(line[0])]  for a in query]
print(line_alpha)
```

Output:

```
[[3, 2], [14, 92, 6], [14, 6], [], [200]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your solution is in the check for `a[0] == line[0][0]`.

Breaking this down you'd have

- `a` is every entry on the `query` array. So `a[0]` will have the values `b, a, abcd, gagioheo, cb` on each iteration.
- `line` is every entry on the `lines` array. Making `line[0]` represent the first element on the array, which is a string. Using `line[0][0]` you are getting the first character on each of the strings. So `line[0][0]` will be the values of `b, a, a, b, a, c`

The entries that are not working on your solution are because it's attempting to check if `abcd == a`, `gagioheo == g` and `cb == c`.

One possibility to solve this issue is by using the `startswith` method on the `line[0]` entries.

```
lines = [['bcac', '3'], ['abcd', '14'], ['abccjg', '92'], ['bcaddgie', '2'], ['abcd', '6'], ['cb', '200']]
query = [['b'], ['a'], ['abcd'], ['gagioheo'], ['cb']]

line_alpha = [[int(line[1]) for line in lines if line[0].startswith(a[0])] for a in query]
print(line_alpha)
```